# preserve whitespace while iterating over a file in bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, whitespace

I need to iterate over the lines of a text file in bash, and I want to preserve whitespace. The final goal is to feed [this line](https://github.com/greg0ire/git_template/blob/master/template/hooks/junkchecker/pre-commit#L16) phrases that could contain a whitespace.

So, given a phrase_file containing

```
xdebug
var_dump
 dump(
pwet
meuh
coin
```

when I try this :

```
while read -r PHRASE
do
    echo "$PHRASE"
done < phrase_file
```

The output is :

```
xdebug
var_dump
dump(
pwet
meuh
coin
```

Where did the whitespace before `dump()` go , and how can I get it back?

Comment: Checking the code in the github link you provided, I see you are missing double quotes almost everywhere. It is good practise to use them, since the lack of them will make your commands break if you happen to use some content with spaces in it. See the difference between `ls "my file"` than `ls my file`, which will try to `ls` both `my` and `file`. Pasting the code in [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) may be helpful to find these kind of things.

Comment: Wow thanks for that, I'll try to update that this weekend

Comment: Also, I know I'm using a lot of backticks when I should use `$()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`$REPLY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) variable, which captures the entire line:

```
while read -r; do
    echo "$REPLY"
done < phrase_file
```

Note that if you name a variable (like `PHRASE` in your example), then `$REPLY` is not set.

Comment: Thank you, accepted : https://github.com/greg0ire/git_template/commit/cf9393fd0e27fcaeec41753983f1b52f3485ee17

Comment: I consider myself somewhat of a Bash expert, and I cannot believe I never knew about `read`'s `-r` parameter or the `$REPLY` variable.  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `IFS` variable to empty:

```
while IFS= read -r var;
do
   echo "$var"
done < file
```

Which returns:

```
$ while IFS= read -r var; do echo "$var"; done < file
xdebug
var_dump
 dump(
pwet
meuh
coin
```

From [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

> IFS= prevents trimming of leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

`-r` treats the input literally, but supplying an argument to `read` causes the line to be split according to `IFS`, a side-effect of which with the default value is to remove leading and trailing whitespace. As Tom Fenech pointed out, `bash` `read` can omit an argument, with the unsplit output stored in `REPLY`. If you don't want to use `REPLY`, you can simply set `IFS` to a null string to prevent word-splitting.

```
# all uppercase variable names are reserved for the shell;
# put at least one lowercase letter or number in your names
while IFS= read -r phrase; do
    echo "$phrase"
done < phrase_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the lowercase / uppercase tip, I'll try to bear that in mind!